# Why were the Martians 'envious' of us, and why did they attack?

Tags: war-of-the-worlds

In H.G Wells's *War of the Worlds*, the Martians are described as envious.
What about earth makes them envious?
And is the answer to this different between different versions of the story (ie. 2005's movie).

Comment: Mars is small, barren and desolate.

Comment: If you owned Mars and I owned Earth, you wouldn't be envious?

Comment: They don't have barbecue.

Comment: Or water, for that matter.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I might want to add (IDK if this is canon to the original novel), in Sherlock Holmes's War of the Worlds, someone (I don't remember who) remarks that the fighting machines seemed familiar with water during the last stand of thunder child.

Comment: @MahmoudSalaheddine It's not canon for either Sherlock Homes or for War of the Worlds.  But Mars did have water millions (billions?) of years ago, so that may be what was referred to (there's also theories that there may still be water frozen underground).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This is covered in the preamble to [Chapter One](https://www.fourmilab.ch/etexts/www/warworlds/b1c1.html) of the original source novel by H. G. Wells.

In short, their world isn't just cold, it's *cooling* to the point that life is becoming unpleasant. The Martians clearly see that this trend will continue until life on the planet becomes non-viable.

Apologies for the length of the quote, but it's all quite relevant.

> **The secular cooling that must someday overtake our planet has already gone far indeed with our neighbour.** Its physical condition is still largely a mystery, but we know now that even in its equatorial region the midday temperature barely approaches that of our coldest winter. Its air is much more attenuated than ours, its oceans have shrunk until they cover but a third of its surface, and as its slow seasons change huge snowcaps gather and melt about either pole and periodically inundate its temperate zones.
>
> **That last stage of exhaustion, which to us is still incredibly remote, has become a present-day problem for the inhabitants of Mars. The immediate pressure of necessity has brightened their intellects, enlarged their powers, and hardened their hearts. And looking across space with instruments, and intelligences such as we have scarcely dreamed of, they see, at its nearest distance only 35,000,000 of miles sunward of them, a morning star of hope, our own warmer planet, green with vegetation and grey with water, with a cloudy atmosphere eloquent of fertility, with glimpses through its drifting cloud wisps of broad stretches of populous country and narrow, navy-crowded seas.**

There also seems to be a philosophical element at play, with the Martians feeling that it's their right to fight for the possession of the Earth if they so choose. Also, that we (inferior creatures) should be exterminated simply due to our fundamental inferiority.

> **The intellectual side of man already admits that life is an incessant struggle for existence, and it would seem that this too is the belief of the minds upon Mars.** Their world is far gone in its cooling and **this world is still crowded with life, but crowded only with what they regard as inferior animals.** To carry warfare sunward is, indeed, their only escape from the destruction that, generation after generation, creeps upon them.

---

As regards the film(s), radio play and TV adaptations, they all start semi-identically, referencing the Martian's "envious eyes" but none seem to go into any greater detail regarding their long-term motivation.

Comment: So that's why we have global warming?! To keep the Martians happy?!

Comment: @corsiKa - I, for one welcome our new Martian Overlords!

Comment: "Its air is much more attenuated than ours" ... What does that mean?

Comment: It means it's lower pressure (thinner), like Earth's air gets at high altitude. A planet's mass determines its gravitational field, which determines how much of an atmosphere it can retain.

Comment: The chances of anything coming from Mars are a million to one ...

Comment: @themathemagician - So they say. And yet they came.

Comment: And that's why we dropped a giant ice-cube in the Atlantic Ocean. Thus solving the problem of Martian Invasion once and for all.

Comment: @Ber- Is that an intentional reference to *Futurama*?

Comment: The "our own warmer planet, green with vegetation and **grey** with water" part (emphasis mine) is interesting. It's hard to realize now that, before we had pictures of the Earth from space, people seriously had no idea what the Earth would look like from space. (Or maybe the Martians are colorblind? I had a roommate once who couldn't see red, due to an old head injury; red things looked gray to him.)

Comment: @TheMathemagician - [...but it just might work!](http://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/Million-to-one_chance)

Comment: @ruakh - dishwater. The oceans only LOOK blue from space because you're seeing them through the atmosphere, which makes *everything* look blue (if it's in sunlight. If there's no sunlight everything looks black. Or at least black-ish. True story...). The real color of the oceans is "dirty-dishwater gray-ish-green-ish". Especially during a storm...and there's always a storm. No matter where I go...always a storm. "Oh, go to Majorca, it's always sunny there!", they say. Balls! I go, it rains for two weeks straight, with a hurricane tossed in for fun. Rain? Don't *talk* to me about rain!!!

Answer (score 32):

While the other answers are what I'd actually answer, too. Here's

### What a teacher would want to hear:

H.G. Wells is being allegoric. The Martians are an allegory to Imperialist Europeans. Their reason "envy" is critique directed at colonization of Africa. Envy being one of the classical sins, is morally judged as a negative trait. The Martians' judgment of humans as inferior is equivalent to reasoning of slave traders of the time. The asymmetric Martian-human war is mirroring European conquest against then less-developed Africa.

### Your question then becomes:

Why would Europeans want to colonize Africa?
For resources and to solve their own problems of

- population density
  There were too many people to be sustained by their current environment. Just like the Martians couldn't survive on Mars much longer.
- "insufficient" cheap labor in other colonies
  This would be America in the real world. It's a bit of a stretch but the Martians used captured humans to fertilize the land in their own cruel way. How many slaves died working in the fields?
- societal gap in wealth
  Simple men could make a "fortune" (or at least gain some land) when going into the colonies. This promise combined with risks due to population density reduced the societal pressure to have riots in imperialist countries. This is one of the few points not addressed in the story: The Martians are displayed as homogenous people, who don't turn on each other. Maybe we can learn from them in that regard?

Well, and hubris, of course.

H. G. Wells suggests the idea of a critique against colonialism in the following passage:

> And before we judge them [the Martians] too harshly, we must remember what ruthless and utter destruction our own species has wrought, not only upon animals, such as the vanished Bison and the Dodo, but upon its own inferior races. The Tasmanians, in spite of their human likeness, were entirely swept out of existence in a war of extermination waged by European immigrants, in the space of fifty years. Are we such apostles of mercy as to complain if the Martians warred in the same spirit?

— Chapter I, "The Eve of the War" (taken from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_War_of_the_Worlds#Colonialism_and_imperialism)

### Finally

The ending of the story unveils its moral: Germs, the simplest known life form defeat the invaders revealing their hubris. They should not have thought too low of "inferior" life forms. As well we humans should not consider each other to be of less value.

### TLDR

It wouldn't make a good story, if the Martians didn't attack.

Comment: Your choice of username is a bit surprising, since this is, in fact, an answer.

Comment: My username reflects that I tend to not answer questions in their original form or any classical sense but try to look behind. I'm not answering "Why are the Martians envious" but change the question to "What's behind the whole thing of the Martians being envious?" .

Comment: Also, I dislike non-content related answers. I hated having to write "what the teacher wants to hear" but that was mostly because we had to interpret bullshit stories with no real substantial social critique.
I like the idea of reading a great story which secretly bashes humanity for its stupid quarrels.

Comment: Makes sense. Welcome to the site!

Comment: It's certainly an interesting approach. You have my +1

Comment: I appreciate this approach; while out-of-universe answers on this site are generally based on creators' statements, there's certainly often room for a critical viewpoint, especially when discussing works that have been thoroughly studied for decades.

Comment: I disagree; Martians repelling a human invasion by nonviolent resistance would still make a good story.

Comment: That's not a teacher, its an indoctrinator, someone seeking to impose a specific narrative on history or literature for the benefit for a particular political class or ideology. This is the kind of analysis one could expect from a Fascist or Stalinist perspective. There is zero evidence that War of the Worlds is an allegory for imperialism and colonialism and much evidence that it isn't. 1) Like almost all Victorian intellectuals e.g. Marx, Wells was a supporter of colonialism as a means of improving the lot of "lessor" races.

Comment: 2) Whereas Wells and his readers would have seen colonialism as overall positive e.g. the elimination of slavery, a vast reduction in violence, especially smaller feuding wars, etc. The Martians in WoW simply seek th extermination of humanity and the earth's native biosphere. It's telling that the Martians are depicted as being just big brains, which the evolutionary theory of the day, which assumed progressive evolution, indicated that the Martians were evolutionary more evolved than humanity.

Comment: 3)  The horror element of the story is the idea that white humans aren't the pinnacle of (progressive, non-Darwinian) evolution and that a more "advanced" species might be out there which could smash us like bugs. Humanity survives in the story, not from its own efforts, but from the dumb luck that that Martians had no immunity to some earth microbes.

Comment: In short, your interpretation is a massive anachronism. It's as valid as claiming that medieval peoples saw some dark moral Henry V crushing victory at Agincourt, when in that era, it made him respected literally world wide as the perfect king. Likewise, it's equally anachronistic to impose the  the utterly reflexive, mindless and ahistorical inverse-jingoism that the Left has adopted after the failure of Marxism/Communism to offer an alternative form of Western culture/economic, imperialism, one under control of intellectuals, instead of fading aristocracies and economic creatives.

Comment: @TechZen: "Death of the Author" means that anachronism is irrelevant. We just have to scratch out the "H. G. Wells is being", to make it a perfectly sound reading. And your "that's no teacher, it's an indoctrinator" claim only makes sense if a teacher **only** wanted this exact answer. NoAnswer didn't say that, and Lit teachers generally don't. Although they often do want you to *be able to give* particular ideological readings (post-colonial, feminist, Marxist...), that doesn't mean they expect you to believe in those ideologies.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "*The Martians are an allegory to Imperialist Europeans. ... The Martians' judgment of humans as inferior is equivalent to reasoning of slave traders of the time*"? That makes no sense to me. Slavery in Africa in the 1890s was practised by Africans and Arabs. The imperialist Europeans didn't practise it, and abolished it in areas they colonised.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Perhaps the reference concerns the [Atlantic Slave Trade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlantic_slave_trade) where Africans were sold by other western Africans to western European slave traders.

Comment: @Armfoot, that can't be the explanation, unless the War of the Worlds was written 60 years before it was published (and  30 years before its author was born).

Answer (score 15):

### Their world is too cold

> And we men, the creatures who inhabit this earth, must be to them at
>   least as alien and lowly as are the monkeys and lemurs to us. The
>   intellectual side of man already admits that life is an incessant
>   struggle for existence, and it would seem that this too is the belief
>   of the minds upon Mars. Their world is **far gone in its cooling** and
>   this world is still crowded with life, but crowded only with what they
>   regard as inferior animals. **To carry warfare sunward** is, indeed, their
>   only escape from the destruction that, generation after generation,
>   creeps upon them.

Mars has grown too cold for the Martians to continue living there any longer, and so they must migrate to a world closer to the sun in order to survive.

Given that the actual temperature of Mars is about -55 degrees Celsius on average, this does not seem too surprising (though estimates of Mars's temperature were unreliable when *The War of the Worlds* was written)
.